# Circuit for Li-ion cell cycling testing

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, testing

I'm researching lithium-ion cells and want to construct a physical setup to test how a Li-ion cell's behavior changes over many discharge-charge cycles, i.e. gather data similar to [image: cycles]

I plan to use Arduino architecture to charge and discharge a cell automatically. Voltage and current will be measured with the Adafruit INA219.

Starting from discharge, if the voltage drops below 2.7 V a switch should disconnect the load and connect the cell to the charging system, for which I will likely use a TP4056 breakout board (e.g. [this](https://eu.nkon.nl/robotdyn-tp4056-micro-usb-lader-1a.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAyfybBhBKEiwAgtB7fkWzbAW0rW09XC7mlnCaZg5Zee3RQId7OUjGNWWuZXZ6NAVrJKJB2BoC0swQAvD_BwE)). Once full the switch should disconnect the charger and reconnect the load. It's important that everything happens without human intervention. I've drawn the circuit in KiCAD below.

[image: example circuit]

B- and B+ indicate the leads on the charger breakout boards. The load is represented by a lamp. The switch component is just a random one I picked in KiCAD and is not representative of a thought-out design. I'm using a single 18650 cell, so no need for balance charging, etc.

My question is: will this work like this?

Online searches are all about circuits with solar cells attached and included charge controllers, but I don't think that is applicable to my circuit. The power supply will come from a wall socket converted to 5 V DC.

I feel like I am missing components or trying to do something really stupid. I would appreciate any help or a push in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Is the [continuous current rating of 30mA for the ADG419](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/adg419.pdf) adequate?  It also has a typical resistance of 24 ohms.

Comment: I picked a random component for the switch and it is not representative of a thought-out design. I will edit to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't (sorry). The 0.5 C charging and 1 C discharging current is on the order of 1 to 10 A (depending on the capacity of the Li-ion cell under test). For that kind of current, you need a relay, not an analog switch. For even larger Li-ion cells, the current is on the order of 100 A, for which you need a contactor.

Use a SPDT relay: C contact to the Li-ion cell, N.O. to the charger, N.C. to the load. Add a buffer between your microcontroller GPIO and the relay coil, which draws more current than a GPIO pin can provide.

However, I would not do any of that. I would buy an [off-the-shelf Li-ion cell tester](https://www.amazon.com/18650-capacity-tester/s?k=18650+capacity+tester). They can be as cheap as [$ 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZVGZ8ST).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would also prefer an off-the-shelf solution, but wouldn't I still need some type of switch to change from the capacity tester to the battery charger? I haven't been able to find an OTS component that can do both charging and discharging and that is what confuses me.

Comment: That switch is built into a battery tester. As I am sure you understand, this problem was already solved and products are sold that handle the entire process of testing Li-ion cells.

Comment: The cheap ones don't seem to. I guess I'll have to keep searching. And yes you did answer my initial question. Thank you.